# Website User Creation in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, single-sign-on

I have a main website hosted on one server and another secondary website, a subdomain of the main one, on another server. I've implemented SSO across the sites so that when a user logs on to the primary website, he is automatically logged on to the secondary website as well; this only works if the user exists as an account on both websites (they're different systems but both ASP.NET websites using forms authentication).

I need to change the authentication routine on the primary website to make a call to the secondary website, passing over the username. If the user doesn't exist on the secondary website, their account is created using the username. Note that the password is not required on the secondary site as users can only log in via the primary site.

My question is then: what's the best way to achieve the above?

I don't think I can simply encrypt the username on the main website and send that over, decrypting it on the secondary site (both sites have the same machine key) because it could easily be "spoofed" so presumably there must be some way of passing a token that the secondary website can use to validate that the request came from the primary website. Is there some way I could use cookies to store an encrypted version of the username? If so, how could I do that and is it a better approach than a URL with the appropriate query string parameters.

It must be a reasonably common scenario but I can't find any definitive guides (best practice) on how to do what I need to do - any suggestions would be very welcome.

I've now been tasked to provide the user creation via a web service instead. This means it should be a bit easier because I don't have to redirect a user to a page on my web site; instead, I only need to service a request to create the user.

To protect the details of the user to be created, I think I only need to utilise HTTPS but based on what I was saying earlier, I thought I can also use the machinekey encryption as well. My next question then, is how should my client pass the paramters to my web service? Should I just use an encrypted parameter or should I embed the parameters in the request header?

Answer (score 0):

Use Oauth protocol described in [Draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31)

Here is Dotnet implementation
[Oauth dotnet library](http://dotnetopenauth.net/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

OAuth sounds very powerful but I think it's possibly overkill for what I need. I can encrypt the username easily enough using the machine key so I guess what I'm looking for is some way of then supplying a token with the request but the user could surely copy the URL and query string parameters and just make a simple change to run the user creation feature again. I need to ensure that the request came from the primary website.